# find the student which has maximum score in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

The schema for the student is as follows

```json
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "pranay kumar",
  "scores": [{
      "score": 120,
      "type": "exam"
    },
    {
      "score": 8,
      "type": "quiz"
    },
    {
      "score": 43,
      "type": "homework"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to find the name of the student who has the highest max by combining his three marks. I able to combine student all marks with this query

```js
db.student.aggregate([{$project:{"name":1,total:{$sum:["$scores.score"]}}}])
```

but I am facing a problem in getting the maximum total value.

Comment: like this? https://mongoplayground.net/p/n3M0kSsNE5p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `$project` stage: [Use `$sum` in `$project` Stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/#use-in--project-stage) to calculate the total score.
2. `$sort` stage: sort descending by `totalScore` field which was created by the previous stage.
3. `$limit` stage: limits the number of documents

Raw MongoDB aggregation pipelines:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      name: 1,
      totalScore: {
        "$sum": "$scores.score"
      }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { totalScore: -1 } },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eTrhLMfXsWr)

Or, use Mongoose [`Model.aggregate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#Model.aggregate()) helper functions to build aggregation pipelines.

```
// "mongoose": "^7.2.1",
const result = await Student.aggregate()
  .project({
    name: 1,
    totalScore: {
      "$sum": "$scores.score"
    }
  })
  .sort({ totalScore: -1 })
  .limit(1)
```